# Wavesurfer.js not loading locally or from server

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

Would anyone be able to spot the issue here?

```
<script>
  var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
    waveColor: 'violet',
    progressColor: 'purple'
  });

  var song = 'http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3'
  wavesurfer.load(song);
  wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {wavesurfer.play();});
</script>
```

The above code example from the wavesurfer site is working. If I intitialize the variable with the SAME mp3 locally:
    var song = 'audio/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3'

or I initialize the variable from a server: 
    var song = 'http://jamesdoe.byethost9.com/jonikae/audio/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3'

neither will work. Is anyone able to identify why wavesurfer will not cooperate?

Comment: did you then include the waveSurfer script? Any errors in console (`F12` function key), what does the network tab indicate? ...

Comment: ah! should have checked console. great catch: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://jamesdoe.byethost9.com/jonikae/audio/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: why am I able to go cross-origin on the working url?

Comment: Have you read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040507/wavesurfer-js-not-loading-locally-or-from-server?answertab=votes#tab-top) ? Can you clarify this case?

Comment: OK, @AliaksiejMaroz I've moved the script outside of the <body> tags and included the .js script locally: <script src="wavesurfer.min.js"></script>

I receive the following error: wavesurfer.html:16 Uncaught TypeError: WaveSurfer.create is not a function(…)

Comment: @James and have you added a container with id="waveform" inside the <body></body>?

Comment: @AliaksiejMaroz yes, sir. 

<script src="wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
  </head>


    <body>

    <div id="waveform"></div>

    </body>
    <script>
    var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({

Comment: @James can you paste all your code here? The code below (at the answer) works perfectly.

Comment: sure @AliaksiejMaroz

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="waveform"></div>
</body>
<script>
var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
    waveColor: 'violet',
    progressColor: 'purple'
});
var song = 'http://jamesdoe.byethost9.com/jonikae/audio/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3';
wavesurfer.load(song);
wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
    wavesurfer.play();
});
</script>
</html>

Comment: @James you should try this [link](http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3) for **var song**

Comment: @Aliaksiej Maroz. that's the problem. when I use that link it's fine. When I type the other link in the address bar it works fine. When I try to use the link that actually needs to work, no success. :(

Comment: @James it's about CORS you know, you should use another server that allowed to get cross domain requests, or configure this one if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to include Wavesurfer.js to your document. Then **you should have any container in document** (that you picked to 'container' property WaveSurfer.create({});)
Also **is important to run script after container initialization** (better at the end of document, when container has been created).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.0.52/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="waveform"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
             container: '#waveform',
             waveColor: 'violet',
             progressColor: 'purple'
         });

         var song = 'http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3'
         wavesurfer.load(song);
         wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {wavesurfer.play();});
    </script>
</html>
```

**UPD**
Also there is a mistake in the include script at the wavesurfer-js website.

```
<scriptsrc="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.0.52/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
```

It should be like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.0.52/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you @aliaksiej for the suggestions. I was able to use a dropbox link as a workaround. You are truly appreciated!